# Holoview plots do not show/appear/display in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, holoviews

I'm trying to make a Holoviews Sankey plot in Jupyter notebook (running Jupyter notebook using Pycharm), but the Sankey plot does not appear after the block is executed.

First I import required packages and set 'bokeh' as Holoviews extension. Using holoviews 1.10.9 and jupyterlab 0.35.4.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

After performing some data wrangling, I prepare a dataframe 'private_investments_grouped' with 3 columns (source, target, value).

I then execute the following code to make the Sankey plot for a sub-dataframe:

```
hv.Sankey(private_investments_grouped.loc[1:7]).options(label_position='left')
```

No plot appears in the output block, no pop-ups, no error messages. It appears the code executes, but no visualization appears.

I can use the 'bokeh' renderer in a Python file in Pycharm and store the Sankey plot as a html file, which works fine. However, I'd like to see the plot in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I can't comment about PyCharm, but in a regular Jupyter notebook be sure that the Sankey line is the last expression in the Jupyter cell; that's what gets displayed.